# React Trying to do a while loop to display a n number of elements before a adding a element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a react app that displays 20 products after those a add keeps the rest of the products idle and displays another 20 with its add when you reach the bottom of the last lot of products displayed. 
I created a while loop in a function that splits the arrays (this works). when I bring the code thats in render (the timeAgo and Prods const) and try adding a while loop to display the split arrays I get an error:

Before I showed all the products with the const timeAgo and Prods in the render but didn't have the while loops in it, it just maped thought all the products and displayed.

This is my react code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Loading } from './LoadingComponent';
const API = 'http://localhost:3000/products';


class Products extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: [],
      percentage: '',
      isLoading: false,
      error: null,
    };
  }

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    fetch(API)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error('Something went wrong ...');
        }
      })
      .then(data => this.setState({ products: data, isLoading: false }))
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }

sortPrice = () => {
    const { products } = this.state;
    products.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price)    
    this.setState({ products })
  }

sortSize = () => {
    const { products } = this.state;
    products.sort((a, b) => a.size - b.size)    
    this.setState({ products })
  }


sortId = () => {
    var reA = /[^a-zA-Z]/g;
    var reN = /[^0-9]/g;
    const { products } = this.state;  
    products.sort(function sortAlphaNum(a, b) {
    var aA = a.id.replace(reA, "");
    var bA = b.id.replace(reA, "");
    if (aA === bA) {
        var aN = parseInt(a.id.replace(reN, ""), 10);
        var bN = parseInt(b.id.replace(reN, ""), 10);
        return aN === bN ? 0 : aN > bN ? 1 : -1;
    } else {
        return aA > bA ? 1 : -1;
      }
    })
    this.setState({ products })
  }



displayContent = () => {

    const { products } = this.state;  
    var arrays = [], size = 20;

  var arrayslenght = arrays.length;
  var i = 0;

    while (products.length > 0){
        arrays.push(products.splice(0, size));
    }
    console.log(arrays);






  const timeAgo = (prevDate) => {
        const diff = Number(new Date()) - prevDate;
        const minute = 60 * 1000;
        const hour = minute * 60;
        const day = hour * 24;
        const month = day * 30;
        const year = day * 365;
        switch (true) {
            case diff < minute:
                const seconds = Math.round(diff / 1000);
                 return `${seconds} ${seconds > 1 ? 'seconds' : 'second'} ago`
            case diff < hour:
                return Math.round(diff / minute) + ' minutes ago';
            case diff < day:
                return Math.round(diff / hour) + ' hours ago';
            case diff < month:
                return Math.round(diff / day) + ' days ago';
            case diff < year:
                return Math.round(diff / month) + ' months ago';
            case diff > year:
                return Math.round(diff / year) + ' years ago';
            default:
                return "";
        }
    };

  const Prods = () => {
    return (
    <div>
       <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12">
                <button onClick={this.sortPrice}>sort by price lower to higher</button>
                <button onClick={this.sortSize}>sort by size small to big</button>
                <button onClick={this.sortId}>sort by Id</button>  
            </div>  
        </div>
         while (arrayslenght > i) {
            {arrays[i].map(product =>

            <div key={product.id} className="row">
                <div className="col-4">
                  <p> Price: ${(product.price/100).toFixed(2)}</p>
                </div>

                <div className="col-4">
                  <p style={{fontSize: `${product.size}px`}} > {product.face}</p>
                </div>

                <div className="col-4">
                  <p>Published: {timeAgo(new Date(product.date).getTime())}</p>
                </div>

            </div> 
         )}

         i= i+1;

         <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12">
                <p>ADD</p>
            </div>
        </div>

  }
         <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12">                
                <p>"~END OF CATALOG~"</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
};



  }




  render() {


    this.displayContent();


    const { products, isLoading, error } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <p>{error.message}</p>;
    }
    if (isLoading) {
      return  <Loading />;
    }
    return (
      <Prods />

    );
  }
}

export default Products;
```

This is my error

Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

117 |                 
  118 |                  while (arrayslenght > i) {

> 119 |                         {arrays[i].map(product =>
>         |                                ^
>     120 |
>     121 |                         
>     122 |

I am really new to react so I am not sure this is the write way to do what I am trying to do I am a bit lost.

this is some content from localhost:3000/products

```
 {
    "id": "33480-rdt892kej5",
    "size": 19,
    "price": 762,
    "face": "( .-. )",
    "date": "Thu Nov 07 2019 17:15:33 GMT-0500 (Colombia Standard Time)"
  },
  {
    "id": "71197-jvsw3t5vmun",
    "size": 35,
    "price": 318,
    "face": "( .o.)",
    "date": "Sun Nov 10 2019 15:52:51 GMT-0500 (Colombia Standard Time)"
  },
  {
    "id": "52383-rv7ozq0t5md",
    "size": 32,
    "price": 234,
    "face": "( `·´ )",
    "date": "Wed Nov 06 2019 01:43:26 GMT-0500 (Colombia Standard Time)"
  },
  {
    "id": "5171-cy5v55aenm",
    "size": 32,
    "price": 25,
    "face": "( ° ͜ ʖ °)",
    "date": "Tue Nov 05 2019 09:44:45 GMT-0500 (Colombia Standard Time)"
  },
  {
    "id": "24915-kunbaov27g",
    "size": 14,
    "price": 924,
    "face": "( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)",
    "date": "Mon Nov 11 2019 03:54:58 GMT-0500 (Colombia Standard Time)"
  },
  {
```

Comment: Could you create example in https://codesandbox.io/ ? I couldn't figure out from this code snippet.

Comment: Here is my link: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-shaw-9f6gu      
I have never used codesandbox.io so let me know if I have done something wrong and you cannot see it.

Comment: @Natasha Can you please share some sample data of products as well ?

Comment: I edited my question with some sample data from localhost:3000/products I know if has 500 elements in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is pretty much self explanatory, I am still confused about the adding an ad part but this is how you should write React

```
import React from "react";
import { Loading } from "./LoadingComponent";

class Products extends React.Component {
  // No need for a constructor
  // for just defining the state.
  // it would've been useful if we
  // wanted to use a prop value as
  // the initial state
  state = { ... };

  _injectAdsInList = list => {
    // an array of your ads
    const AdsList = [];

    if (Array.isArray(list)) {
      const insertAdAt = 20;
      const productsAndAdsList = list.map((item, index) => {
        // not sure about this calculation
        // but this should be done here
        if (index % insertAdAt === 0) {
          // its the 20th item insert an ad
          return AdsList[0];
        }

        // otherwise insert the item
        return item;
      });

      this.setState({ productsAndAdsList });
    }
  };

  _getProducts = () => {
    // make the fetch call here
    // also it would be easier if you
    // use a library like axios (https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)
    // for making http requests
    axios.get(SOMEURL).then(list => this._injectAdsInList(list));
  };

  _sortPrice = () => {
    const { products } = this.state;
    // instead of mutating the origin array
    // create a new one, and update the state
    const sortedProducts = products.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price);
    this.setState({ products: sortedProducts });
  };

  _sortSize = () => {
    const { products } = this.state;
    // instead of mutating the origin array
    // create a new one, and update the state
    const sortedProducts = products.sort((a, b) => a.size - b.size);
    this.setState({ products: sortedProducts });
  };

  _sortId = () => {
    // there might be a better way
    // to do all of this
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // I personally prefer not to make any
    // http calls directly in componentDidMount
    // instead, creating a new function makes sense
    this._getProducts();
  }

  render() {
    const { productsAndAdsList, isLoading, hasError } = this.state;

    // show spinner
    if (!hasError && isLoading) {
      return <Loading />;
    }

    // show error
    if (hasError && !isLoading) {
      return <p>error.message</p>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          {/* sorting buttons */}
          <div className="col-12">...</div>
        </div>
        {productsAndAdsList &&
          productsAndAdsList.map(item => (
            <div key={item.id} className="row">
              <div className="col-4">
                <p> Price: ${(item.price / 100).toFixed(2)}</p>
              </div>

              <div className="col-4">
                <p style={{ fontSize: `${item.size}px` }}> {item.face}</p>
              </div>

              <div className="col-4">
                <p>Published: {timeAgo(new Date(item.date).getTime())}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Products;
```

Comment: I copied your code and added  state = { 
 products: [], 
      isLoading: false,
      error: null, }; 
I get no erros. I also added my sorting buttons but thats all that is displayed in the browser I also installed and added axios

Comment: This is most probably because `productsAndAdsList` is empty. Did you change the _getProducts method? Once we get the products, you'll have to pass the array to _injectAdsInList method

Comment: Yes 
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/products').then(list => this._injectAdsInList(list));

Comment: Change `return Ad[0];` with `return AdsList[0];` in _injectAdsInList method. I fixed it in the above code.

Comment: Ukw, could you share your code on JSFiddle or something? That might be better

Comment: Here is a link to stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hc7vom

Comment: No issues in the component, can you verify two things: axios.get is successful and we are getting a list of products from localhost:3000, console.log(productsAndAdsList) in the render just before the if conditions and what is the value, it surely shouldn't be undefined

Comment: I get undefined when Iput  console.log(productsAndAdsList) in the render just before the if conditions

Comment: should AdsList be save in state?

Comment: Just try removing the if condition in _injectAdsInList method

Comment: If I remove the if condition in _injectAdsInList I get this error in the browser Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): list.map is not a function. runs in the console

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the nested `while` and `map` inside the render. You need to update these to return components: `return ()` when nesting like this.

I don't have the sample data from your project, but you should be able to follow a similar example below:

```
  const categories = [
    {
      name: "books",
      products: [{ name: "The Hobbit" }, { name: "Dune" }]
    },
    {
      name: "films",
      products: [{ name: "Star Wars" }, { name: "Ghostbusters" }]
    }
  ];

  ...

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Demo For Nested Loops</h1>
      {categories.map(category => {
        return (
          <>
            <h2 key={category.name}>{category.name}</h2>
            {category.products.map(product => {
              return <h4 key={product.key}>{product.name}</h4>;
            })}
          </>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
```

As an example:

[Codesandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-bose-uoyqd)

Answer (score 1):

The problem which you are asking here arises because

1. Your  tag is not closed properly
2. React can render one div  only it means your code must return one 
   div  not multiple

Now your code is having 2 separate  div element that is causing issue.

**New changes**

```
const Prods = () => {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12">
              <button onClick={this.sortPrice}>
                sort by price lower to higher
              </button>
              <button onClick={this.sortSize}>sort by size small to big</button>
              <button onClick={this.sortId}>sort by Id</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          while (arrayslenght > i){" "}
          {
            <div>
              arrays[i].map(product =>
              {
                <div key={product.id} className="row">
                  <div className="col-4">
                    <p> Price: ${(product.price / 100).toFixed(2)}</p>
                  </div>
                  ) }
                  <div className="col-4">
                    <p style={{ fontSize: `${product.size}px` }}>
                      {" "}
                      {product.face}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-4">
                    <p>
                      Published: {timeAgo(new Date(product.date).getTime())}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              }
              i= i+1;
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12">
                  <p>ADD</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          }
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12">
              <p>"~END OF CATALOG~"</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

It will fix your current issue.

Check out here - https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-cache-u3zw3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I would actually refrain from doing this sort of manipulation in the render method. Instead, do this in the method where you are getting the first i.e. `getListOfProducts()` or something

Comment: Also, using React.Fragment is also a good idea instead of introducing new <div>s

Comment: I change my Prods code for yours and now I get this error:
 Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

  164 |
  165 |
> 166 |   render() {
      |            ^
  167 |
  168 |
  169 |         this.displayContent();

this is refering to the { after the render.

Comment: @Natasha maybe you are missing out something else as per the code you give me. i have fixed the issue and in the link which i shared it to you i am not getting any errors as well. But anyways will try to fix new bug as well kindly update your errors in codesandbox link which you have provided before .

Comment: @AjayGupta I agree with you the code needs to be reflector a lot. so many features shouldn't reside in just one function and ofcourse react fragment as well .

Comment: Ok I copied you code from the link and I don't see why I should be getting this error:
  Line 152:27:  'product' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 154:35:  'product' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 158:46:  'product' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 160:24:  'product' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 165:52:  'product' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 198:13:  'Prods' is not defined    react/jsx-no-undef

Comment: Are you getting that error in your local system ?? @Natasha and obviously you will get that error cause you didn't store product in your state that's why it cannot find product

Comment: In my console and browser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202667/discussion-between-samarth-saxena-and-natasha).